# How do I read/write to files in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

1.I am new to coding and I store all my python code in:

```
C:\Users\(MyName)\Documents\Python Scripts
```

2.I made a txt file in notepad (list.txt) and stored it in the same location

3.I want to read the file so in Spyder:

```
file = open('list.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

4.I get an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'list.txt'
```

5.Where am I supposed to store my txt file? And how do I read it?

Comment: Are you sure the script and file are in the same location, and you're running them from that location? Make sure your working directory in Spyder is `C:\Users\(MyName)\Documents\Python Scripts`

Comment: now it says  runfile('C:/Users/(MyName)/Documents/Python Scripts/(FileName.py)', wdir='C:/Users/(MyName)/Documents/Python Scripts')

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the script in the same directory as the file, or change the path to the correct directory path.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is using `numpy.loadtxt` and `numpy.savext`. Eg:

```
import numpy as np

example_list = [1,2,3,4]
np.savetxt('example_file.txt',example_list)
data = np.loadtxt ('example_file.txt')
print(data)

>>> [1. 2. 3. 4.]
```

It should work on the same directory your console or py file are located

Comment: Numpy has nothing to do with not being able to find the file.